# ajax with jquery and json and php file. is it advisable to use json here?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have not worked with json yet. and have no idea how it works
I want to use jquery for performing ajax with php file. is it advisable to use json here. 
heard from someone that json is light weight. Is that true? if yes how would i use json for ajax-php peration with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](http://json.org/) is an information interchange format based on JavaScript literal notation (but is actually a subset of literal notation, you may only use strings, numbers, objects, booleans and arrays, from memory).

Unless you need to receive data back, you won't use it. It is lightweight compared to something like XML.

If you need to get JSON using jQuery, you can use the high level AJAX API call called [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which is as simple as....

#### jQuery

```
$.getJSON('path/to/whatever.php', function(obj) {  
    alert(obj.name);
});
```

#### PHP

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('name' => 'bob'));
```

If you wanted to throw away requests that don't look like AJAX, use this...

```
if (isset($_SERVER['X-REQUESTED-WITH']) AND $_SERVER['X-REQUESTED-WITH'] !== 'XMLHttpRequest') {
   die('XHR only.');
}
```

Comment: huhmmm... ok will give a try to jason with jquery and see.. thanks

Comment: This json code is not working . any idea why so?? $.getJSON('fruitvarities.php', {fruitName:1}, function(data){
 
 $('#testarea').html(data); 
 
     });

Comment: and this is my php file <?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
echo "Here is my sample text.to check if json is working";
?>

Comment: @Parag `fruitvarities.php` isn't returning JSON, just a string.

Comment: huh...!!! i actually wanted to grab some data from database(ex property listings) format it in table format and put them up using ajax json, php. its not possible with json?

Comment: @Parag Read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) carefully, I think you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/